# Issue with comparing two arrays and merging based on the merged array with distinct objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

Initially the array `$scope.distinctCourseUsers` will be empty, after every dynamic new response I would be appending all the objects to the previous list including new set of objects 
and then eliminating the duplicates of an array by using reduce method and storing back to `$scope.distinctCourseUsers`

```
$scope.courseUsers = response;
Array.prototype.push.apply($scope.distinctCourseUsers,response); 
distinctCourseUsers = result = $scope.distinctCourseUsers.reduce((unique, o) => {
    if(!unique.some(obj => obj.Id === o.Id )) {
    unique.push(o);
    }
    return unique;
},[]);
```

---

```
$scope.courseUsers = response;
```

For the I response two new array objects will be stored into `$scope.courseUsers`

```
console.log($scope.courseUsers);

(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {Id: 22410, Name: "test01", RoleType: "XL Teacher", IsEnrolled: false, EnrolledOn: "", …}
1: {Id: 22411, Name: "test02", RoleType: "XL Teacher", IsEnrolled: false, EnrolledOn: "", …}
```

Merging the empty `$scope.distinctCourseUsers` array with the response stored in `$scope.courseUsers`

```
Array.prototype.push.apply($scope.distinctCourseUsers,response); 
console.log($scope.distinctCourseUsers);
```

For the II response there will be two new objects, so appending previous Array List(2) + (New Array List(2) + Previous Array List(4)) Totally (2+2+4=6) to the `$scope.distinctCourseUsers` array list

```
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {Id: 22410, Name: "test01", RoleType: "XL Teacher", IsEnrolled: false, EnrolledOn: "", …}
1: {Id: 22411, Name: "test02", RoleType: "XL Teacher", IsEnrolled: false, EnrolledOn: "", …}
2: {Id: 22410, Name: "test01", RoleType: "XL Teacher", IsEnrolled: false, EnrolledOn: "", …}
3: {Id: 22411, Name: "test02", RoleType: "XL Teacher", IsEnrolled: false, EnrolledOn: "", …}
4: {Id: 22412, Name: "test03", RoleType: "XL Teacher", IsEnrolled: false, EnrolledOn: "", …}
5: {Id: 22413, Name: "test04", RoleType: "End user", IsEnrolled: false, EnrolledOn: "", …}

// The below reduce opertator will eliminate all the redundant objects
distinctCourseUsers = result = $scope.distinctCourseUsers.reduce((unique, o) => {
    if(!unique.some(obj => obj.Id === o.Id )) {
    unique.push(o);
    }
    return unique;
},[]);


console.log(distinctCourseUsers);
```

**Actual & Expected Result:**

```
0: {Id: 22410, Name: "test01", RoleType: "XL Teacher", IsEnrolled: false, EnrolledOn: "", …}
1: {Id: 22411, Name: "test02", RoleType: "XL Teacher", IsEnrolled: false, EnrolledOn: "", …}
2: {Id: 22412, Name: "test03", RoleType: "XL Teacher", IsEnrolled: false, EnrolledOn: "", …}
3: {Id: 22413, Name: "test04", RoleType: "End user", IsEnrolled: false, EnrolledOn: "", …}
```

---

The above approach is inefficient, due to performance overhead associated with appending previous list of objects. Is it possible to eliminate the duplicate at the first place mentioned in below code

```
Array.prototype.push.apply($scope.distinctCourseUsers,response);
```

How would you reduce the code to make it efficient enough to get the above result?

Answer (score 0):

Actually did a [blog post on this recently](https://cutterscrossing.com/development/javascript/ecmascript/2019/05/29/js-tip-simple-array-of-unique-items/), and it's dead simple. I have several options for you here, so make sure you get to the end.

You can use `Array`s and a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to get unique items. Here's the basic idea using simple values.

```js
const arr = [19,22,7,12,6,85];
const arr2 = [22,8,3,19,45];
const newArr = [...arr, ...arr2];
// newArr equals [19, 22, 7, 12, 6, 85, 22, 8, 3, 19, 45]
const uniqueArr =  = Array.from(new Set(newArr));
// uniqueArr equals [19, 22, 7, 12, 6, 85, 8, 3, 45]
```

It is important to remember that objects are by ref, so if you have two objects that look the same (structurally) that doesn't mean they are the 'same', so think about that when using a Set. However, if the objects were pushed to each array by ref, then this should still work for you. If object ref is in question (at all) then you might want an intermediary.

```js
const intermediary = [...myTrueVar];
intermediary.push(myObj);
const keys = itermediary.map((it) => it.key));
const uniqueKeys = Array.from(new Set(keys));
myTrueVar = intermediary.filter((it) => uniqueKeys.includes(it.key))
```

Or, you could get really crazy

```js
const intermediary = [...myTrueVar];
intermediary.push(myObj)
const stringed = intermediary.map((it) => JSON.stringify(it));
myTrueVar = Array.from(new Set(stringed)).map((it) => JSON.parse(it));
```

But that's probably overkill, and probably assumes the object keys are always in the same order, so the first bit intermediary is probably the better option (and probably less overhead).

Also remember that, while the `Set` constructor is supported by IE 11, `Array.from` is not (and deconstruction even less so), so if you're stuck in the past you'll need to transpile it down with Babel.

**Or**, you could just simply check your initial array for the item and conditionally add it when necessary. Probably the most performant, since your only adding one user at a time.

```js
!$scope.distinctCourseUsers.find((user) => user.Id === response.Id) &&
  $scope.distinctCourseUsers.push(response)
```